# Digital vs printed rendering of TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, printing

This may be related to printers setup and/or flattening options of pdf files (I have no clue about) so I might be off topic but I would need advice/guidelines on the following problem.

Here is my TikZ picture with dots on the pdf.

[image]

Once printed, the dots are replaced with straight lines.

[image]

I `\includegraphics` the pdf of the following `standalone` TikZ.
I don't this it has to do with my diagram itself but in case

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
level distance=1cm,
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.0cm},
        level 3/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
        level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},                
    ]
    \node (cash) {Cash} 
    child { node {Term}
        child { node (future) {Futures}}            
        child { node[top color=red,bottom color=red,rounded corners,minimum height = 0.7cm,text=white] (forward) {Forwards}
            child { node {Bonds}
                child { node {Fix}}
                child { node {Floating}}
            }
            child { node {Swaps}
                child { node {IRS}}
                child { node {TRS}}
            }
            child { node (options){Options}
                child { node (vanillas) {Vanillas}}
                child { node (exotics) {Exotics}}
            }
        }       
    }   ;
    
    \draw[latex-latex, dotted] (forward.west) -- (future.east) ;
    \draw[latex-latex, dotted] (forward.north) -- (cash.east) ;
    \draw[latex-latex, dotted] (future.north) -- (cash.west) ;
    \draw[latex-latex, dotted] (options.north) -- (cash.east) ;
    \draw[-latex, dotted] (vanillas.south) to [bend right] (exotics.south) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It says: `Undefined control sequence. \aclp`... (although this is probably a printer problem)

Comment: @Rmano My bad, I left some `acro` commands. MWE updated and compiling.

Comment: Ok, now compiles ok here, without any problem. (Although you had the `\aclp{}` command in the *node names*, which is a no-no...)

Comment: If a simple `\draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (1,0);` replicates your problem (you can test it with various line widths and/or dash patterns), then perhaps your printer doesn't support dash pattern.

Comment: ...and it prints ok on a Xerox printer. So it's you printer/driver which is the culprit here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles in TeXShop(fully updated) using MacTeX(fully updated) and prints on Brother HL2250DN printer directly from mac(fully updated) preview.

[image: Photo of a printout of the code]

Comment: Thank you for your sanity check! I did mine too :) With some time spent on the zillions options of my printer, one of them regarding "flattening" enabled me to have the correct result. merci !